# Reset Filter for Google Map Markers Using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I'm attempting to create a map of filterable sports venues using Google Maps API and KnockoutJS. The markers are filtering just fine, other than when the user types an input and deletes all characters (no characters in search bars...all markers should return to visibility). I've tried several different things to make all of the markers visible on this occurrence, including using the setVisible function various places, however, just can't seem to pinpoint the solution. I know it is probably something simple, but I'm having a block.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <container>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <div id='menu'>
        <li>
          <i class='material-icons'>&#xE5D2</i>
        </li>
      </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id='overmap'>
    <div id='filter'>
      <div class='filter-bar'>
        <h2>Search Pittsburgh Sports Venues</h2>
        <input id='userFilter' data-bind="value:userSearch, valueUpdate: 'input'" placeholder="Type a venue name..."/>
      </div>
     <ul id="list" data-bind="foreach: filterVenues">
      <a href='#'>   <li>
      <h3 data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.setVenue"></h3>
    </li></a>


      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id='map'>
    </div>
  </container>



  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/knockout-3.4.2.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA_WObUiYD7YpoYufR84re1LZHAJeAGXkY&v=3&callback=initMap">
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/app.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/menu.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var map;
var marker;
var infowindow;
var wikiURL;
var text;
var venueInfo;
var markers = [];
var markerNames = [];
var wikiURLs = [];
var venueArray = [];
var blackMarker = ('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_black.png');
var yellowMarker = ('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_yellow.png');
var currentMarker;
var currentVenue;
var venueList;
var filterVenues;
var clicker;
var venueMatch;
var venue;
var i;
var userSearch;
var setVenue;
var clickedVenue;

//The Model - Pro/Collegiate Stadiums in PGH, Pa.
var venues = [
  {
    name: "PNC Park",
    lat: 40.446855,
    lng: -80.0056666,
    marker: '',
    info: ''
  },
  {
    name: "Heinz Field",
    lat: 40.4466765,
    lng: -80.01576,
    marker: '',
    info: ''
  },
  {
    name: "PPG Paints Arena",
    lat: 40.439593,
    lng: -79.989338,
    marker: '',
    info: ''
  },
  {
    name: "Highmark Stadium",
    lat: 40.4362358,
    lng: -80.00959209999999,
    marker: '',
    info: ''
  },
  {
    name: "Peterson Events Center",
    lat: 40.443828,
    lng: -79.962283,
    marker: '',
    info: ''
  }
];


function ajaxCall(i){
  var venue = venues[i];
  wikiURL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' +venue.name+ '&format=json&callback=wikiCallback';


  wikiURLs.push(wikiURL);

  $.ajax ({
      url: wikiURL,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data){
            text = data[2];
            venues[i].info = text[0];


              if (venue.info === undefined) {
                venue.info = 'Whoops! Our data never showed up. Check out '+venue.name+' on Wikipedia for more!';
              }
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: venue.lat, lng: venue.lng},
                icon: blackMarker,
                map: map,
                name: venue.name,
                draggable: false,
                content: '<h2>'+venue.name+'</h2><p>'+venue.info+'</p>',
                visible: true
              });



                markers.push(marker);
                venue.marker = marker;
                markerNames.push(marker.name);



            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: this.content
                });



                marker.addListener('click', function(){
                  infowindow.setContent(this.content);
                  infowindow.open(map, this);
                  for (var i = 0; i<markers.length; i++){
                    markers[i].setIcon(blackMarker);
                  }
                  this.setIcon(yellowMarker);

                });
        }
      });

  }








//capturing locations and names in arrays as we iterate through createMarker function
//marker creator

function createMarker(venue){
for (var i=0; i < venues.length; i++){
ajaxCall(i);
}
}




var viewmodel = function() {


var self = this;


self.userSearch = ko.observable("");
self.venues = ko.observableArray(venues);
this.currentVenue = ko.observable(self.venues()[0]);
this.setVenue = function(clickedVenue) {
  self.currentVenue(clickedVenue);
  google.maps.event.trigger(clickedVenue.marker, 'click');
};


self.filterVenues = ko.computed(function(venue) {
  var search = self.userSearch().toLowerCase();
  if (!search) {
    return self.venues();

  } else {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.venues(), function(venue) {
    if (venue.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1) {
      venue.marker.setVisible(true);
      return true;
    } else {
      venue.marker.setVisible(false);
      return false;

    }


    });
    }


});
};







//Map Initializer

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 40.446855, lng: -80.0056666},
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });


createMarker();

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to display all the markers once the filter is empty would be to update `filterVenues` observable to:

```
 self.filterVenues = ko.computed(function (venue) {
    var search = self.userSearch().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.venues(), function (venue) {
        if (venue.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1) {
            venue.marker.setVisible(true);
            return true;
        } else {
            venue.marker.setVisible(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

2)There is at one more flaw with the provided example. Since the markers are added *asynchronously*, there is no any guarantee that when the map is getting displayed, all the markers are available per every venue.

I would suggest to change the way how filter control is initialized, in particular *bind filter control once the all the markers are initialized*.

```
initMarkers(map, infowindow)
    .done(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
        console.log("map is ready");
    });
```

where we introduce a function to initialize markers:

```
function initMarkers(map, infowindow) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {

        var request = (function (venue) {
            return loadDetails(venue)
                .then(function (data) {
                    venue.info = data[2];
                    if (venue.info === undefined) {
                        venue.info = 'Whoops! Our data never showed up. Check out ' + venue.name + ' on Wikipedia for more!';
                    }
                    createMarker(map, infowindow, venue);
                });
        })(venues[i]);
    }
    promises.push(request);
    return $.when.apply(null, promises);
}
```

and a function for loading Wikipedia data using CORS instead of JSONP (without `callback` parameter):

```
function loadDetails(venue) {
    var wikiURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&origin=*&action=opensearch&search=' + venue.name + '&format=json';
    return $.ajax({
        url: wikiURL
    });
}
```

3)Last but not least, there is no need to create the instance of info window per every marker, instead you could create a *single* instance.

Below is provided the modified example

```js
var blackMarker = ('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_black.png');
var yellowMarker = ('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_yellow.png');
//The Model - Pro/Collegiate Stadiums in PGH, Pa.
var venues = [
    {
        name: "PNC Park",
        lat: 40.446855,
        lng: -80.0056666,
        marker: '',
        info: ''
    },
    {
        name: "Heinz Field",
        lat: 40.4466765,
        lng: -80.01576,
        marker: '',
        info: ''
    },
    {
        name: "PPG Paints Arena",
        lat: 40.439593,
        lng: -79.989338,
        marker: '',
        info: ''
    },
    {
        name: "Highmark Stadium",
        lat: 40.4362358,
        lng: -80.00959209999999,
        marker: '',
        info: ''
    },
    {
        name: "Peterson Events Center",
        lat: 40.443828,
        lng: -79.962283,
        marker: '',
        info: ''
    }
];


function loadDetails(venue) {
    var wikiURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&origin=*&action=opensearch&search=' + venue.name + '&format=json';
    return $.ajax({
        url: wikiURL
    });
}

function createMarker(map, infowindow, venue) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: venue.lat, lng: venue.lng },
        icon: blackMarker,
        map: map,
        name: venue.name,
        draggable: false,
        content: '<h2>' + venue.name + '</h2><p>' + venue.info + '</p>',
        visible: true
    });
    //console.log(marker.name);

    marker.addListener('click', function () {
        if (infowindow.prevMarker)
            infowindow.prevMarker.setIcon(blackMarker);
        infowindow.setContent(this.content);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        this.setIcon(yellowMarker);
        infowindow.prevMarker = this;
    });
    venue.marker = marker;
    return marker;
}

function initMarkers(map, infowindow) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {

        var request = (function (venue) {
            return loadDetails(venue)
                .then(function (data) {
                    venue.info = data[2];
                    if (venue.info === undefined) {
                        venue.info = 'Whoops! Our data never showed up. Check out ' + venue.name + ' on Wikipedia for more!';
                    }
                    return createMarker(map, infowindow, venue);
                });
        })(venues[i]);
    }
    promises.push(request);
    return $.when.apply(null, promises);
}



var viewmodel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.userSearch = ko.observable("");
    self.venues = ko.observableArray(venues);
    self.currentVenue = ko.observable(self.venues()[0]);
    self.setVenue = function (clickedVenue) {
        self.currentVenue(clickedVenue);
        google.maps.event.trigger(clickedVenue.marker, 'click');
    };

    self.filterVenues = ko.computed(function (venue) {
        var search = self.userSearch().toLowerCase();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.venues(), function (venue) {
            if (venue.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1) {
                venue.marker.setVisible(true);
                return true;
            } else {
                venue.marker.setVisible(false);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
};


function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 40.446855, lng: -80.0056666 },
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ""
    });

    initMarkers(map, infowindow)
        .done(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
            //console.log("map is ready");
        });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
#map{
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
 </script>
 
  
  
  <div id='overmap'>
      <div id='filter'>
        <div class='filter-bar'>
          <h2>Search Pittsburgh Sports Venues</h2>
          <input id='userFilter' data-bind="value:userSearch, valueUpdate: 'input'" placeholder="Type a venue name..." />
        </div>
        <ul id="list" data-bind="foreach: filterVenues">
          <a href='#'>
            <li>
              <h3 data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.setVenue"></h3>
            </li>
          </a>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Thank You, Vadim. Even though I understand it may not be best practice, is there also any way to accomplish the marker reset by only modifying my existing viewmodel?